# Looping over a list of dictionaries with DataFrames

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I have a list with input files stored as dictionaries that represent imported Excel files. Each dictionary has multiple sheets stored as DataFrames.

I want to store the same key (sheet) of different dictionaries (Excel files) appended to each other while breaking the sheet when three NaN values appear in a column. I initialise a new dictionary, that should have the same keys (sheets) as the dictionaries (Excel files), but now all data is appended to this single dictionary `d_sheets`

To do this, I use the code below:

```
input_files = []
for file in read_input:
    input_file = pd.read_excel(io=file, sheet_name=needed_sheets, dtype=str)
    input_files.append(input_file)

d_sheets = {}
for dictionary in input_files:
      for sheet_name in sorted(dictionary):
            d_sheets[sheet_name] = pd.DataFrame()
            if sheet_name != 'Sheetname1':
                cell = dictionary[sheet_name]['Columnname1']
            else:
                cell = dictionary[sheet_name]['Columnname2']
            three_NaNs = cell.isna() & cell.shift(-1).isna() & cell.shift(-2).isna()
            first_instance = cell[three_NaNs].index.min()
            good_data = dictionary[sheet_name][cell.index <= first_instance]
            d_sheets[sheet_name].append(good_data)
            d_sheets[sheet_name] = pd.concat([d_sheets[sheet_name], good_data], axis=0)
```

It appears that for a single dictionary (Excel file) the boolean statements do their work and the keys are stored in `d_sheets`. However, I cant find a working way to loop over the dictionaries in `input_files`.

What might cause the problem that I cannot iterate over the items of the list `input_files` and store all sheets in `d_sheets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue as the DataFrame initialization should not be inside the for-loop in `d_sheets[sheet_name] = pd.DataFrame()`. This way, each iteration the loop clears the DataFrame and then performs the calculations. In the end, this results in the latest Excel file only as output, instead of all the files merged.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your "breaking sheet" strategy (pardon me if I did not understand) here is a script that might do the job:

```py
import pandas as pd

# helper function to break sheets with 3 consecutive NaN in any column
def df_breaker(df):
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    nan_ind = pd.DataFrame({k:[0] for k in df.columns})
    for row in df.iloc:
        nan_ind=(row.isna()*nan_ind)+row.isna()
        if (nan_ind.iloc[0]>=3).any():
            return res.iloc[:-2]
        res=res.append(row)
    return res

# shall be broken after second row
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,1,None,None,None],'c2':[5,6,7,8,9]})
# shall not be broken 
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[10,None,12,None,14],'c2':[None,16,None,18,19]})
# shall not be broken 
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[20,21,22,23,24],'c2':[25,26,27,28,29]})
# shall not be broken 
dfd = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[30,31,32,33,34],'c2':[35,36,37,38,39]})

input_files = [{'sheet1':dfa, 'sheet2':dfb},{'sheet1':dfc, 'sheet2':dfd}]


d_sheets ={}
for key in input_files[0]:
    d_sheets[key]=pd.concat([df_breaker(k[key]) for k in input_files])
```

Comment: Hi Gillu, thanks for the nice function that does exactly what I need. However, in my script the function is not iterating over the list of dictionaries and instead uses a single Excel file. Would you help me direct what the discrepancy can be between our lists? My list is created with a for-loop with the pd.read_excel function

Comment: I have added the input_files list in the code. Does this make it clear why the loop over the items of the list is not working?